# comparar objetos em javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

neste script, que compara objetos em javascript, mesmo que eu passe valores iguais (ao meu entender, mas que ao que tudo indica está errado), o retorno continua sendo false. alguém poderia me ajudar a entender melhor esse conceito?

```
let deepEqual = (a, b) => {
    let aKeys = Object.keys(a);
    let bkeys = Object.keys(b);
    if (aKeys.length !== bkeys.length) {
        return false
    }
    let equals = aKeys.some((chave) => {
        return a[chave]!== b[chave]
    });
    return !equals
}
let obj = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
let obj2 = {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2};
let obj3 = obj2;
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj));
// true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj2));
// false
console.log(deepEqual(obj2, obj3));
// true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2}));
// false
```

valeu ;)

Answer (score 3):

O problema dessa função é que compara só o primeiro nível de profundidade do objeto. Ou seja, quando compara os valores numéricos tudo bem, mas quando compara o valor de uma propriedade que é um objeto, como `{is: "an"}`, e em cada um dos objetos, então vai dar false, pois `{is: "an"} === {is: "an"}` dá `false`.

O que tens de fazer é com que essa função seja recursiva e ao detectar um objeto como valor dessa chave/propriedade então deve chamar-se a si própria e analizar esse valor da chave/propriedade como um objeto e ir fazendo isso a cada nível de profundidade desse objeto.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
let deepEqual = (a, b) => {
  let aKeys = Object.keys(a);
  let bkeys = Object.keys(b);
  if (aKeys.length !== bkeys.length) {
    return false
  }
  let equals = aKeys.some((chave) => {
    if (typeof a[chave] === 'object') return !deepEqual(a[chave], b[chave]);
    else return a[chave] !== b[chave]
  });
  return !equals
}
let obj = {
  here: {
    is: "an"
  },
  object: 2
};
let obj2 = {
  here: {
    is: "an"
  },
  object: 2
};
let obj3 = obj2;
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj)); // true
console.log(deepEqual({foo: 123}, {bar: 345})); // false
console.log(deepEqual(obj, obj2)); // true
console.log(deepEqual(obj2, obj3)); // true
console.log(deepEqual(obj, {here: {is: "an"}, object: 2})); // true
```